# Using reflection instead of a long switch statement

Tags: java, performance, memory, reflection, switch-statement

Hey so I have a pretty long switch statement that calls a method based on a string like so

```
private void callMethod(String name) {
    switch(name) {
        case "blah":
            blah();
            break;
        case "method":
            method()
            break;
    }
}
```

etc.

So I used reflection to shorten the code

```
try {
    Method method = ClassName.class.getDeclaredMethod(name, args);
    method.invoke(args);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // switch default
}
```

Just wondering if using reflection like this is bad on memory/performance. I only call this function every so often.

Edit: The reason I used this is because the user has the option to start a different part of the game based on the string they enter in. Each method that starts the event is named after what they need to type in.

Comment: It's risky if the user has any ability to control the input to your call method function as it could expose code that they are not intended to be able to run.

Comment: Reflection does have an impact on the performance of your application, a profiler can be used to determine the precise difference. However, it seems possible that this is an xy problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Can you describe the requirements that led you to creating this function? It's possible that there is a solution which requires neither a hardcoded switch statement nor reflection code.

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing your use case. If this is only called internally and the performance doesn't matter reflection can be a good solution.

Comment: The only methods in that class are the ones I want to be called. There's no method they can call that isn't intended. The way I am calling this function is when the user types in the string them self. Each method starts a different part of the game.

Comment: there is little input on what drove you to writing this piece of code, but why instead of `new MyClass(). callMethod("foo")`
you simply do not do the following: `new MyClass(). foo()`

Comment: Sorry MarcinL I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: 'I only call this function every so often'.  The performance _deficit_ of reflection will be of little significance.  The time it takes someone to type the name of a method will be _orders of magnitude_ longer.  I'd just go with the reflective approach.  Honestly, the best solution here would be to just put this in and test if you find the performance unreasonable with it, but I would be _astonished_ if you could really notice a difference in realtime only calling it occasoinally.

Answer (score 3):

Using reflection like that is a bad idea. Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) for information about drawbacks.

About the performance:

> "Because reflection involves types that are dynamically resolved, certain Java virtual machine optimizations can not be performed. Consequently, reflective operations have slower performance than their non-reflective counterparts, and should be avoided in sections of code which are called frequently in performance-sensitive applications."

Don't think of reflection as a normal tool like `String` or `ArrayList` and rather try to implement a better software design that fits your needs. Then you will have to think about reflection very rarely.

---

Edit:

The performance hit is of course debatable but be aware of the other downsides. As others already stated are there security issues, e.g. when a user "calls" a method that is not intended to be "callable" directly by the user. Another downside is that you potentially have problems in your code which are not findable at compile time because of the reflection. And many more downsides ...

In my opinion reflection should be used mostly to solve technical problems that are not directly related to production code, e.g. in testing of your software.

Comment: The reason I need this is because it's the user who is entering the string. Should I just use a really long switch statement then?

Comment: I don't know the rest of your program so I'd say yes. Just use the long switch statement because of the drawbacks of reflection. But I guess my initial answer is strict and more general about reflection as well. So if you think it's worth it here to shorten things then go on and use it. ^^

Comment: @NicholasM The user needs a few seconds to type in the string. The reflection may cost a few nanoseconds. Any more performance thoughts ? Still, reflection feels hacky.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is usually the worst way to do things.  It’s slow, it can’t be optimized at runtime, and the compiler can’t flag mistakes.  And as kpie pointed out, letting user input directly control which method is executed is a security hole.

Any long `switch` statement can be replaced with a Map.  In your case, a `Map<String, Runnable>` would suffice:

```
Map<String, Runnable> actions = new HashMap<>();
actions.put("blah", this::blah);
actions.put("method", this::method);

// ...

Runnable action = actions.get(name);
if (action == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name: " + name);
}
action.run();
```

Comment: It’s not correct to say “it can’t be optimized at runtime”. Optimizations are just harder and may hit more implementation specific limitations. Since performance is a secondary concern, you should have starting with the compile-time safety. Then, maintenance (e.g. refactoring support). Then, potential performance problems… Now, thinking about it, there’s another gotcha, security concerns. What happens, if someone passes a string not intended to be supported, but happening to match an existing method…

Comment: Every method in that class is supported

Comment: @NicholasM And if you or someone else adds a public method to that class a year from now, will you/they remember that any end user has the power to invoke it?

Comment: yeah it's just a little project for me. I can see how it would be an issue but it doesn't really affect me

Comment: It can even invoke `private` methods unintentionally. @NicholasM that’s perhaps the most fundamental misconception in programming, “*I will always remember this constraint/ never have to change or reuse this code*”